# JCR (JSR-170) connector for Lotus Notes

Tags: java, lotus-notes, jcr, connector, jsr170

I'm looking for JCR (JSR-170) connector for Lotus Notes Domino Server 7 for integration between our customer Domino server and our software.

Does anybody has an experience in dealing with such JCR connector? I found only day.com [connector](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/crx/connectors/domino/current.html) but not sure it if fits me.

Comment: Why aren't you sure? What's the issue?

Comment: Could you please clarify your questions? You mean my concerns regarding day.com connectors or something else?

Comment: Yep; the day.com connector is the only one I'm aware of. What makes you think it won't "fit"?

Comment: Lack of additional info beyond day.com website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Oracle WebCenter [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12483_01/webcenter.1013/b31074/jpsdg_content.htm) for examples of how such integration works within Oracles development framework. That information is specific to WebCenter, but should give you a better idea of how the integration works in practice than what's on www.day.com.